# Mathematica 12 crashes when I use F1 for documentation

Tags: documentation, crash

I have been using Wolfram Mathematica for about 3 years and never experienced this before. Out of the blue, today it started behaving like this; anytime I try to look into the documentation of an specific command using F1, Mathematica crashes, leaving my unsaved word completely gone.

I am currently on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: I also encountered this problem a few days ago, and I re installed 12.1.1 to solve the problem, but I do not know the specific reason.

Comment: This occassionaly happens to me, on both Ubuntu and Windows 10. I don't know what could be the cause.

Comment: @Pancho: I have been having the same problem with MMA v11 with window 7. I still have it.

Comment: having the same issue, it's extremely annoying. I don't always remember to save documents the whole time.

Comment: Ubuntu20.04,Mathematica 12.1-12.3 have no problems, but when I try to use Mathematica 13.0, the problem you described occurs but not very often. May 13.x or some edition will solve it.